# Snowflake query a partition with filter condition

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions, partitioning

I have a Key-value based records in the Snowflake table, where for a given product_id there are dozens of Key-value pairs records. See the example below:

[image]

```
with t1 (product_id, key, value) as 
    (
    select 101, 'grade',                'high' union all
    select 101, 'expense_cost',     'high' union all
    select 101, 'maintenance_cost', 'medium' union all
    select 102, 'grade',                'medium' union all
    select 102, 'expense_cost',     'high' union all
    select 103, 'expense_cost',     'high' union all
    select 103, 'maintenance_cost', 'medium' 
    )
    select * from t1;
```

Given this data model, the requirement is to fetch product_ids that match the filter criteria of key values.

**Example 1**: Fetch all product_id where key=(grade) is having value=(high or medium) & key=(expense_cost) has value=(high)

**Example 2**: Fetch all product_id where key=(grade) has value=(high) & key=(maintenance_cost) has value=(high or medium)

I am able to solve this requirement using a Snowflake `PIVOT` function, which first converts Key-Value data structure to Columnar data structure and then applies a `Filter` condition using the `WHERE` clause. Is there a better way to solve this problem without using PIVOTs, for example by using some Window functionality, etc.?

My PIVOT based solution for Example 1:

```
with t1 (product_id, key, value) as 
(
select 101, 'grade',                'high' union all
select 101, 'expense_cost',     'high' union all
select 101, 'maintenance_cost', 'medium' union all
select 102, 'grade',                'medium' union all
select 102, 'expense_cost',     'high' union all
select 103, 'expense_cost',     'high' union all
select 103, 'maintenance_cost', 'medium' 
)
select * from (
select product_id, key, value 
  from t1 
  where key in ('grade','expense_cost','maintenance_cost')
) pivot(min(value) for key in ('grade','expense_cost','maintenance_cost'))
as p (product_id, grade, expense_cost, maintenance_cost)
where grade in ('high','medium')
and expense_cost in ('high');
```

NOTE: IN case of using Window function, the output must only the contain the rows which qualify or pass the filter condition. The output must not contain all the records in the qualified partition.

Comment: Do you have to match both the requirements in the same query, Or either of those? The way you have it laid out is confusing because it makes it look like an OR instead of AND.

Comment: Both are separate requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding my solution below which is an improvement on @Lukasz Szozda's solution which had the following 2 problems:

a. For each Attribute in the Filter criteria his code needed to add an
additional Window function that increased the Snowflake computation
time linearly.

b. There were dozens of Attributes that needed to be removed from the resultset and adding so many Window functions for each of those Attributes would make the SQL query very bloated.

Here is my improved code:

```
with t1 (product_id, key, value) as 
(
select 101, 'grade',                'high' union all
select 101, 'expense_cost',     'high' union all
select 101, 'maintenance_cost', 'medium' union all
select 102, 'grade',                'medium' union all
select 102, 'expense_cost',     'high' union all
select 103, 'expense_cost',     'high' union all
select 103, 'maintenance_cost', 'medium' 
)
select * , 
 (CASE 
      WHEN key = 'grade' AND value IN ('medium', 'high') THEN TRUE
      WHEN key = 'expense_cost' AND value = 'high' THEN TRUE
      ELSE FALSE
  END) AS is_allowed
from t1
WHERE key IN ('grade', 'expense_cost')
QUALIFY COUNT_IF(is_allowed=TRUE) OVER(PARTITION BY product_id) = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

The pattern to use is `QUALIFY` combined with `COUNT_IF`. It could be pivoted if needed afterwards:

> "Requirement 1: Fetch all product_id where grade is (high or medium) & expense_cost = high"

```
with t1 (product_id, key, value) as 
    (
    select 101, 'grade',                'high' union all
    select 101, 'expense_cost',     'high' union all
    select 101, 'maintenance_cost', 'medium' union all
    select 102, 'grade',                'medium' union all
    select 102, 'expense_cost',     'high' union all
    select 103, 'expense_cost',     'high' union all
    select 103, 'maintenance_cost', 'medium' 
    )
select * 
from t1
qualify COUNT_IF(key='grade' AND value IN ('medium', 'high')) 
            OVER(PARTITION BY product_id) > 0
    AND COUNT_IF(key = 'expense_cost' AND value = 'high') 
            OVER(PARTITION BY product_id) > 0;
```

Output:

[image]

---

> Requirement 2: Fetch all product_id where key=(grade) has value=(high) & key=(maintenance_cost) has value=(high or medium)

```
with t1 (product_id, key, value) as 
    (
    select 101, 'grade',                'high' union all
    select 101, 'expense_cost',     'high' union all
    select 101, 'maintenance_cost', 'medium' union all
    select 102, 'grade',                'medium' union all
    select 102, 'expense_cost',     'high' union all
    select 103, 'expense_cost',     'high' union all
    select 103, 'maintenance_cost', 'medium' 
    )
select * 
from t1
qualify COUNT_IF(key='grade' AND value IN ('high')) 
            OVER(PARTITION BY product_id) > 0
    AND COUNT_IF(key = 'maintenance_cost' AND value IN ('medium','high'))
            OVER(PARTITION BY product_id) > 0
    AND COUNT_IF(key='expense_cost' AND value IN ('high')) 
           OVER(PARTITION BY product_id) = 0  -- explicitly excluding
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This solution is very close to the desired result. However, I notice some records in the resultset which are not part of the QUALIFY condition? For example, in Requirement 2 the result is showing the record where expense_cost='high'. This particular condition was not mentioned in the QUALIFY. Your result returns the entire partition block in the resultset if it matches the QUALIFY. However the desired result should only have the actual records, not the entire partition block which match the filter condition, ?

Comment: @sunny_dev It was not mentioned to remove it,  though it is very easy to achieve by adding: `AND COUNT_IF(key='expense_cost' AND value IN ('high')) OVER(PARTITION BY product_id) = 0`. The condition per entire product_id group so if there is need to exclude something it has to be stated explicitly.

Comment: Can you kindly update your answer with the new complete solution?

Comment: @sunny_dev Sure, I have extended the answer

Comment: This is not a feasible solution, given that there are more than 100 such Key-value pairs associated with each Product_Id. We can't possibly write a SQL where we have to mention 2 Key-Value pairs which match and the remaining 198 Key-value which doesn't match inside the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier and more self-documenting if you sub-select qualifying product_ids using conditional-aggregation, then filter on qualifying product_ids plus the conditions in the where clause. Below is a demo for requirement #2, but you can easily modify it for #1.

```
with t (product_id, keys, value) as 

(select 101, 'grade','high' union all
 select 101, 'expense_cost','high' union all
 select 101, 'maintenance_cost','medium' union all
 select 102, 'grade','medium' union all
 select 102, 'expense_cost','high' union all
 select 103, 'expense_cost','high' union all
 select 103, 'maintenance_cost','medium' ),

product_ids as

(select product_id
 from t
 group by product_id
 having sum(case when keys='grade' and value ='high' then 1 end)>0 and
        sum(case when keys='maintenance_cost' and value in ('high', 'medium') then 1 end)>0)
                            
select * 
from t
where product_id in (select product_id from product_ids) and
    ((keys='grade' and value ='high') or (keys='maintenance_cost' and value in ('high', 'medium')))
```